# Custom error 404 page misconfiguration

Tags: css, html, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file configured:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html
```

This works fine when I type: www.mydomain.com/whatever-to-get-404-error, but, when I use www.mydomain.com/some_folder/whatever-to-get-404-error I get a page without css. My browser starts to look for css in "some_folder", which of course, do not exist.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: surely thats just a relative path vs an absolute one in the HTML for the stylesheet, nothing to do with htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a relative path to your CSS file in your 404 page's markup.  Use an absolute path (easiest way, start the path with `/`).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="404.css">
```

That's a relative `href`, it will look *in the current folder* for `404.css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/404.css">
                                            ^^^
```

That is an absolute path, it will look *in the root folder* for `404.css`.

Comment: To make sure if I get it right: reconfigure 404 page with http://mydomain.com/css/cssfile.css paths to stylesheets?

Comment: You don't need to specify the host, in your example there you could simply set `href="/css/cssfile.css"`

Answer (score 1):

While using absolute URL is best option. In case you have too many places to change then you can try adding this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```